# Jackson prefers private constructor over @JsonCreator when deserializing a class with @JsonValue

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a simple class with a private constructor and a static factory.  I want the class to serialize as a number, so I've annotated the getter for the field with `@JsonValue`.  However, Jackson appears to prefer the private constructor over the static factory, even when I annotate the static factory with `@JsonCreator`.  It works if I annotate the private constructor with `@JsonIgnore`, but that feels a bit off.

I've seen some posts claiming that `@JsonCreator` only works if the parameters are annotated with `@JsonProperty`; however, that seems to be the case for objects serialized as JSON objects.  This object is being serialized as a number, and thus there is no property to supply to the annotation.

Is there something I'm missing?

*example class*:

```
package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;

public class NonNegative {
  private final double n;

  private NonNegative(double n) {
    this.n = n;
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static NonNegative checked(double n) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(n >= 0.0);
    return new NonNegative(n);
  }

  @JsonValue
  public double getValue() {
    return n;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(n);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj instanceof NonNegative) {
      NonNegative that = (NonNegative) obj;
      return Objects.equals(n, that.n);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

*example tests:*

```
package com.example;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class NonNegativeTest {
  private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  @Test
  public void itSerializesAndDeserializes() throws Exception {
    NonNegative nonNegative = NonNegative.checked(0.5);

    assertThat(MAPPER.readValue(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(nonNegative), NonNegative.class)).isEqualTo(nonNegative);
  }

  /* This test fails. */
  @Test(expected = JsonMappingException.class)
  public void itDoesNotDeserializeANegativeNumber() throws Exception {
    MAPPER.readValue(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(-0.5), NonNegative.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried annoting the argument of the checked method with @JsonProperty?

Comment: I have.  It did not help.

Comment: [Maybe relevant](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-paranamer/issues/11).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Indeed Jackson will override JsonCreator method with constructor method in case if parameter is Java standard type. I would say this is a bug in BasicDeserializerFactory#_handleSingleArgumentConstructor method.

So, the problem is that constructor has higher priority then static factory method in case if that constructor and static factory method has regular Java type. There is few ways how to workaround it.

Set creator visibility level to NON_PRIVATE:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(creatorVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NON_PRIVATE)
class NonNegative {
```

Second way is to delete static factory method and use constructor. I moved Preconditions.checkArgument to the constructor (it doesn't do much... Just throw an IllegalArgumentException if condition is not satisfied):

```
public class NonNegative {
  private final double n;

  private NonNegative(double n) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(n >= 0.0);
    this.n = n;
  }

  @JsonValue
  public double getValue() {
    return n;
  }
}
```

Another way is to use @JsonIgnore annotation but you mention that you don't like this approach :)

**Update** I've logged a bug: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/660

**Update** Jackson bug that prefers constructor over static factory method was resolved: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/commit/257ae1c7a88c5ccec2882433a39c0df1de2b73aa

Comment: Thanks, glad to see that this was a bug and not something I was misunderstanding, and very glad to see that it has been resolved.

Comment: Another way is to modify the constructor so it won't be called by Jackson, e.g., adding another argument (perhaps a dummy one). I don't see how that's better than `@JsonIgnore` though...